# UIDocumentBrowserViewController empty Recents list

Tags: ios11

Just experimenting with the UIDocumentBrowserViewController. All is good - opening/creating/saving documents etc.

One odd one though is that the Recents list is not getting populated. Even stranger is that if I tag a document (with a color) it does then appear in the Recents list. If I remove the tag it disappears from the Recents list. The Recents list is behaving more like a tagged documents list!?

Anyone point me at the obvious info.plist switch that I'm probably missing?

Thanks

[UPDATE] Just created a new project and it works fine. Wondering now if the fact that I changed the document type half way through development (info.plist) messed up some kind of recents cache.

Comment: "Wondering now if the fact that I changed the document type half way through development (info.plist) messed up some kind of recents cache." Indeed. If you watch the WWDC 2017 video on this topic, you'll find that a recents cache is exactly what there is.